# Centrar divs que son generados dinámicamente

Tags: html, css

Estoy trantando de centrar una cantidad de divs que no son conocidos de antemano, sino que se van generando a medida que se vayan guardando datos en la bdd.
Con un foreach se van presentando cada uno de los divs pero no logro hacer que se vean centrados en la pantalla. Lo que necesitaria sería algo asi y sucesivamente si se muestran 3, 4 o más:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
            <div class="listado-amigos">

              <?php
              $misAmigos=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM amigos WHERE emisor=:idu OR receptor=:idu && estado=1");
              $misAmigos->bindParam(':idu',$_SESSION['user_id']);
              $misAmigos->execute();
              foreach ($misAmigos as $misA){
              ?>

                <div class="cuadro-amigos">

                </div>

              <?php } ?>

            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.listado-amigos{
  background: url("fondo.jpg");
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #FFC900;
  width: 70%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.cuadro-amigos{
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #FFC900;
  width: 18.65%;
  height: 230px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ejemplo 1**

La forma mas simple parece ser aplicar *FlexBox* a tu diseño, procediendo de esta forma:

- Al div contenedor, es decir al que contendrá todos tus cuadros de información dale un display flex
- Para centrarlos horizontalmente, indica un justify-content con un valor de center
- Al momento los cuadros quedarían pegados, para lograr la separación entre ellos les puedes aplicar un margin con un valor X

```html
      <style>
        .container {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
        }
        .element {
          background-color: crimson;
          color: white;
          padding: 20px;
          margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
        }
      </style>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="element">1</div>
      <div class="element">2</div>
      <div class="element">3</div>
    </div>
```

**Ejemplo 2**

Al momento todos los elementos te quedarían en el mismo renglón y te generaría un scroll horizontal, como no se si es lo que buscas y tal vez no; entonces:

- Al div contenedor le podemos dar un flex-wrap con valor de wrap para que cuando los elementos ya no queden en el mismo renglón entonces los mande al segundo
- La propiedad margin cambiaría y los valores que inicialmente dejé en 0 se cambiarían a una medida X

```html
      <style>
        .container {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        .element {
          background-color: crimson;
          color: white;
          padding: 20px;
          margin: 10px;
        }
      </style>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="element">1</div>
      <div class="element">2</div>
      <div class="element">3</div>
      <div class="element">1</div>
      <div class="element">2</div>
      <div class="element">3</div>
      <div class="element">1</div>
      <div class="element">2</div>
      <div class="element">3</div>
      <div class="element">1</div>
      <div class="element">2</div>
      <div class="element">3</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Para que queden realmente *centrados* el `margin` aplicado debe ser igual a ambos lados, por ejemplo: `margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;`, de lo contrario tendrán una tendencia hacia alguno de los lados y no estarán *totalmente* centrados. Saludos

Comment: Tienes razón @MauricioContreras corrijo

Comment: Genial! Eso era exactamente lo que necesitaba, css no es lo mio para nada jajaj Muchas gracias!